# XAMPP 5.6.3 control panel issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

My XAMPP 5.6.3 shortcut to the control panel was somehow not working in Windows 10, so I deleted the control panel shortcut. Now I have no idea how to get it back. I tried clicking on xampp_start.exe, but it just runs the command prompt. I want the control panel. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP, but it still didn't work for me. The final solution was a replacement of xampp/phpMyAdmin.